# Django dynamic filters operator.or_ & operator.and_

Tags: django, filter, python-3.4

Problem:

I currently have a range of dates which display values in that date range

I want to add a filter that allows values that are expired so will be less than the start date to display first as well as the ones in the date range.

I need to do this with the operator.and_ to join the two conditions that decide if the value is Expired.

Then use the operator.and within my qs_params to add it to my filter.

below is my logic along with the code so far

```
    exp = ("condition_one", False)
    exp_two = ("due_by__lte", start_date)

    if date_range(x,y) or (exp and due_by__lte(x,y))
```

code example so far:

```
  date_range = ["due_by__range", (day_start(start_date), day_end(end_date))]

  exp = ("condition_one", False)
  exp_two = ("due_by__lte", start_date)

  expired = [exp, exp_two]

  test = [Q(expired) for expired in date_range]

      qs_params.append(
            test)


 if qs_params:
        qs = qs.filter(


        )
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: This is really unclear. How do those two snippets relate to each other? And please at least show valid code; this is full of syntax errors, indentation problems, variables that are redefined, calls to things that are not functions...

Comment: I've updated description, the first bit of code is just a logical if statement of what i'm after

Answer (score 0):

I think what you ask for is something like this:

```
query = Q(due_by__range=(day_start(start_date), day_end(end_date)))
query |= Q(condition_one=False, due_by__lte=start_date)
result_qset = mymodel.objects.filter(query)
```